# Select2 "selected": true not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

When parsing the data from the example, the disabled parameter works, but the selected one dosen't. Any ideas why?

Example:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Option 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "Option 2",
      "selected": true
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "text": "Option 3",
      "disabled": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Result from site:
[image]

Select2 version 4.0.3 - link: [Select2 Data Source](https://select2.org/data-sources/formats)
JQuery version 3.0.0

Comment: Is there a working jsfiddle or code snippet?

Comment: What are you expecting the selected parameter to do?

Comment: @Shane I have understood as a way  to pre-select an option.

Comment: I created a JS Fiddle and it seems to be working as expected: **https://jsfiddle.net/gytc59n8/1/**. The selected item is 'Option 2'.

Comment: As you can see from @Abbas comment above, this is working as expected. No issue here.

Comment: After playing a bit around with the jsfiddle @Abbas made I have found the problem. Normally I get the data via the Select2 Ajax call. As fare as I can tell something in there breaks and does so the "selected" parameter isn't working. If instead I do an ajax call in a function and parse it on to the Select2 setup I can get the "selected" parameter working.
I will look a bit more into it and report is as a bug if I find it being that. 
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Are use obtaining the options from an AJAX-source? If this is the case you need to proceed differently for preselection as explain in the middle section of this page: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items

Answer (score 0):

selected parameter did not work for me either. Had to use below workaround to make it work -

```
$(".select").select2({
    data: data_names
});
data_names.forEach(function(name) {
    if (name.selected) {
        $(".select").select2('val', name.id);
    }
});
```